# kubectl describe nodes, reports some error

Tags: kubernetes

I am gettting this error in kubectl `describe nodes nodename`. I just did a google search but nothing useful found , what does this mean.

`Failed to update Node Allocatable Limits "": failed to set supported cgroup subsystems for cgroup : Failed to set config for supported subsystems : failed to write 3783778304 to memory.limit_in_bytes: write /rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes: invalid argument`

Do I need to change some kernel settings using sysctl ?

```
[iahmad@lxplus000 ~]$ kubectl --version
Kubernetes v1.5.2
[iahmad@lxplus000 ~]$ 
[iahmad@lxplus000 ~]$ 
[iahmad@lxplus000 ~]$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"269f928217957e7126dc87e6adfa82242bfe5b1e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-03T15:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.6", GitCommit:"4bc5e7f9a6c25dc4c03d4d656f2cefd21540e28c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-18T08:52:26Z", GoVersion:"go1.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
[iahmad@lxplus000 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the `kubectl/kubernetes` version: this was seen (and fixed) in [kubernetes issue 42701](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/42701)

1.6 should have been patched.
If this is not the same bug, the error message was also seen in [issue 29166](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29166#issuecomment-315787325):

> I just forgot to active back `disk.uuid` after creating back my new VMs!

Comment: looks like my k8s version is fine but do i need to update my kubectl?

Comment: Yes , to be consistent with the kubernetes version